# Change click drag/resize button on keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, window-management

Currently I have to use the <kbd>windows key</kbd> plus `left/right` click to effect my windows, I would like to use Alt for this action.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dconf editor`

Inside `org > gnome > desktop > vm > preferences > mouse-button-modifier`

See below.

[image]